# How to Trigger a workflow when an email is sent to a list in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I am trying to email documents to a list , and i want a workflow to be triggered on these documents when this email is sent to the list.
The workflow should do:-

1. Create a folder with the name of the document.
2. Move the document to the folder that was just created.
3. After 12 hours, the folder and its documents should be moved to another list.

This Image shows my attempt to do the steps mentioned above:-
[image]

can you tell me about the best technique to do this? thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the word list loosely, since you mention documents and folders.

SharePoint has a default security setting that does not allow for workflows to be triggered by emails. This setting can be changed, I have attached an article [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/how-can-i-make-a-workflow-automatically-start-when-an-email-is-received).

Comment: thanks a lot, i have also found this helpful article: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4607.sharepoint-2010-workflows-on-incoming-emails-in-sharepoint-documents-library.aspx